# Why can I access a file from a web server even though the URL doesn't exist?

Tags: web, url, links

**WARNING: IM A TOTAL NOVICE**

So i'm trying to understand how i'm able to access a PDF file from a website on say,

"www.website.com/Documents/Publications/2015/file.pdf"

But www.website.com/Documents doesn't "exist" i.e. it comes up as a broken link.

1) Why can I still access the file?

2) How can I find out what other files reside in the parent directories?

Comment: [Cross-post](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/100605/17633)

Answer (score 1):

Web servers can be set up to disallow access to directories - meaning that you can only access the link `www.mywebsite.com/Documents` if it contains an index file (index.html. index.php etc).

This means that direct file access works, the web server has just been set up not to **list files in that directory**; though you can still access them directly. Google "Apache/nginx directory listings" or something similar to find out exactly how this works.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, HTTP URLs have nothing to do with file systems.

Webmasters *could* map HTTP URLs to files on the file system, but that’s not necessary.

If you visit a URL like `http://example.com/Documents/Publications/2015/file.pdf`, it could be

- a file named `file.pdf` that exists in the folder `/Documents/Publications/2015/`,
- a file named `document_v1.260.pdf`  that exists in the folder `/foobar/`,
- a file named `I-am-not-a-PDF.jpg`,
- a script `pdf-generator.php` that creates the PDF file on the fly,
- or something else.

And even if the URL maps to the file system (like in the first case), it’s not necessarily the case that all parent folders are accessible via URLs. For example, a webmaster could decide to offer content at `http://example.com/Documents/Publications/`, but not at `http://example.com/Documents/`.

(If you’re interested in the technical side, see [my answer to the Stack Overflow question *Are friendly URLs based on directories?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36595114/1591669))